# ¿Es correcto decir "hay X ocurrencias de Y en el CORDE"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, definiciones, sustantivos

Pregunta rápida desde el móvil.

> **[ocurrencia](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Qu7nMUN)**
>   De *ocurrir*.
>
> 1. f. Encuentro, suceso casual, ocasión o coyuntura.
> 2. f. Idea inesperada, pensamiento, dicho agudo u original que ocurre a la imaginación.

Muchas veces tiendo a escribir "hay tantas ocurrencias de X en el CORDE", pero luego me lo pienso porque relaciono *ocurrencia* con esa segunda acepción, como en "hay que ver las ocurrencias que tiene este niño". De hecho, cuando el CORDE muestra resultados habla de "casos" y no de "ocurrencias".

Así que pregunto: ¿es correcto el uso de "ocurrencia" en este caso? ¿Se suele usar así en textos cultos? ¿O es un falso amigo o una importación de su uso en inglés?

Answer (score 4):

Me parece que en esta, como en tantas otras ocasiones, el DRAE se ha quedado corto.

En [este diccionario](https://es.thefreedictionary.com/ocurrencia), encontramos dos acepciones más, derivando la (4) (de sentido más restringido, que es el que nos ocupa en este caso) de la (3) (de sentido más general):

> 3. hecho de acontecer una cosa *No hay que esperar la ocurrencia de un evento desgraciado para prevenir.*
> 4. *lingüística* aparición de un elemento lingüístico en un texto *El texto tiene tres ocurrencias de predicados nominales.*

La lengua es mucho más amplia de lo que decreta la RAE.

Comment: También en WordReference aparece esa acepción: http://www.wordreference.com/definicion/ocurrencia

Answer (score 3):

Parece que sí es correcto. Preguntada a la RAE [en Twitter](https://twitter.com/charliealejo/status/963002673179123712), responden diciendo [lo siguiente](https://twitter.com/RAEinforma/status/963014441745952768):

> En esos contextos, la voz «ocurrencia» signfica 'hecho de ocurrir o producirse', acepción que no se refleja en estos momentos en el diccionario académico, pero que posiblemente se incorporará en próximas actualizaciones.

Tal acepción se puede encontrar en textos escritos, por ejemplo:

> La clase de accidente que predominó fue el choque, con 47 casos (41,5 por ciento), seguido del atropello con 26 ocurrencias (23 por ciento).
>
> El Tiempo, 17/07/1997 (Colombia).

Se ve el uso de "ocurrencia" como sinónimo de "caso".

Comment: "la voz «ocurrencia» signfica 'hecho de ocurrir o producirse', acepción que no se refleja en estos momentos en el diccionario académico, pero que posiblemente se incorporará en próximas actualizaciones." Parece increíble que el DRAE haya omitido una acepción tan obvia, la de un sustantivo derivado de una de las acepciones más comunes del verbo "ocurrir". No se trata de un uso nuevo.